# Transaction over many functions

Tags: php, mysql, sql, transactions

I've got some functions that edit or read my db. Is it a good idea to start a transaction the first thing I do, and commit or rollback it the last thing I do, rather on a per-function-basis?

Does the new or the old values get read if in same transaction, but before a commit?

I want a transaction behavior over all function calls within each page load.

EDIT:

I'm only using simple, single row sql statements. All the logic is done in php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New values are read if in the same transaction.  The idea is that you can view results of an update before committing them, it's not like the transaction hides the changes until you commit them, it just allows you to undo the changes if something went wrong.

Regarding whether or not to do these on a per-function basis, it really depends on what each one is doing, and if they are affecting the same data. If you don't need to check and decide whether to commit/rollback until all of them have finished, then probably fine to keep just one transaction.

Comment: Some functions edit the same data, yes. I would want to rollback as soon as something goes wrong, if it does. Is there any special way to do this "globally" if i'm using PDO?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by globally, but to rollback at the earliest point possible you would want to use some IF/THEN logic to check after each function or group of functions to see whether or not you want to proceed to the next or rollback, then commit after all are finished.

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind using transactions is for situations where all statements need to succeed, or none should.

If you don't use transactions, mysql will treat each statement as a transaction and autocommit after each statement (unless you disable autocommit, then nothing will happen).